# UIAutomation problems accessing TableView

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

Now I'm having the same kind of problem as he [UIAutomation, UITableView inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11022166/1631314), but I can't solve it as he did. I have the similar screen as his with four cells but their names are different. Using the function LogElementTree I've got the same hierarchy as his, but a little bit another. In his case he has got this:

```
UIAWindow
UIATableView

   UIATableCell

      UIATableView

          UIATableCell 1

          UIATableCell 2

          UIATableCell 3

          UIATableCell 4
```

But I've got this:

```
UIAWindow
UIATableCell 1

UIATableCell 2

UIATableCell 3

UIATableCell 4
```

Using his answer I wrote my code:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().cells()["Author"].tap();
```

OR

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().cells()[0].tap();
```

But it didn't work. So could somebody describe how to solve my problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0].tap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0].tableViews()[0].cells()[0].tap();
```